# Problem with RESTAPI data using Angular 6

Tags: angular

while working with restapi in angular am getting the values and I am able to edit also. but the problem is showing error in that corresponding ts file, but it is working. Errors are with " this.details.name, this.details.mobile,this.details.message". why file showing error? please help me.`enter code here`

```
details: any[];
  fullname:string;
  mobileno: string;
  usermessage: string;
  userid: number;

  editUser(rowId: number){
    //alert(rowId);
    var url ="http://cybotrix.com/angularapi/getdetails.php";
    var newJson = {"id": rowId};
    this.httpService.post(url, newJson).subscribe(
      data=>{
        console.log(data);
       this.details = data as string[];
       //console.log(this.details);
       this.fullname = this.details.name;
       this.mobileno = this.details.mobile;
       this.usermessage = this.details.message;
       this.userid = rowId;

      }

    );
```

Comment: What is the result are you getting if you console data?

Comment: Hi Ramya, welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you meant to wrap the above code inside a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized `this.details` with array => `details: any[]`

Just change it to => `details: any = {};`

Also, remove `this.details = data to string[]`. Just initialize it as `this.details = data`;

Here is the updated code:

```
details: any = {};
fullname:string;
mobileno: string;
usermessage: string;
userid: number;

editUser(rowId: number){
  //alert(rowId);
  var url ="http://cybotrix.com/angularapi/getdetails.php";
  var newJson = {"id": rowId};
  this.httpService.post(url, newJson).subscribe(
    data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.details = data;
       this.fullname = this.details.name;
       this.mobileno = this.details.mobile;
       this.usermessage = this.details.message;
       this.userid = rowId;    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the `data` to `string[]`. The array may not have properties such as `name, message` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :-

```
this.httpService.post(url, newJson).subscribe(
      data=>{
        console.log(data);
       this.details = data as string[];
       //console.log(this.details);
       this.fullname = this.details[0].name;
       this.mobileno = this.details[0].mobile;
       this.usermessage = this.details[0].message;
       this.userid = rowId;

      }

    );
```